# Is there anyway to link my oracle database to my react native app?

Tags: oracle, react-native

I am receiving an error overtime I try to launch my project.

```
Android Bundling failed 1605ms
The package at "node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.type here
```

This is my oracle.js file that is causing an error
I assume that oracle cannot be used in react native due to the error

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

async function connectToOracleDB(sqlQuery: string) {
  // Configure database connection
  const connectionConfig = {
    user: '#####',
    password: '#####',
    connectString: '######' // Use the TNS name from the TNS file
  };

  try {
    // Connect to the Oracle database
    const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(connectionConfig);

    // Execute custom SQL query
    const result = await connection.execute(sqlQuery);

    // Release the connection
    await connection.release();

    // Return the result of the SQL query
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

module.exports = connectToOracleDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, react native does not include the standard node lib which is needed for the package you are importing. You will need to find a package that is either specific to RN or doesn't require standard node to use in your project.

More on adding third party packages from RN docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/libraries#does-it-work-with-react-native).